# Confusing result of java replaceAll when matching start of string with space

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = " foo";
System.out.println(str.matches("\\s*foo")); //false
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.getBytes()));//[-30, -128, -123, 102, 111, 111]
```

From above, the first character is not `space`.

```
String replaceStr = str.replaceAll(".*?([a-z]*)", "$1");
System.out.println(replaceStr.equals("foo"));//false
```

above code cannot get only `foo`.

```
replaceStr = str.replaceAll("^.*?([a-z]*)$", "$1");
System.out.println(replaceStr.equals("foo"));//true
```

why have `^`and`$`, then could get only `foo`?

Comment: I copied/pasted your string and the first character  is `\u2005` - *‎2005  FOUR-PER-EM SPACE*. It belongs to `\p{Zs}` category. Seems like you just need `(?U)\\s*foo`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/URLzgC)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, let me know this knowledge.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but how do you know `-30, -128, -123` is `\u2005`

Comment: There is a "magical" Web site :) [Former Rishida Conversion Tools](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.*?` is non-greedy — it will try to match as little as possible while still having the overall match succeed.

Since `[a-z]*` can match zero letters, `.*?([a-z]*)` *can* successfully match the empty string at position 0. So that's what it does.

By appending `$`, you're forcing the regex to extend all the way to the end of the string (if possible), so the `.*?` matches as far as it has to in order to make that possible.

You could also accomplish the same thing by writing `[a-z]+` instead of `[a-z]*`, since that would force the `.*?` to match far enough to let `[a-z]+` match at least one letter.

But the best approach is probably to write:

```
replaceStr = str.replaceFirst("^[^a-z]*", "");
```

which is equivalent to your working example, but much clearer. (`[^a-z]` means "any character besides a–z".)